# APEX JSON Deserialize

Tags: json, salesforce, apex-code

I have JSON string that has nested objects with dynamic names that vary each time. For an instance:

```
{
    "Objects": {
        "dynamicName1": {
            "name": "test"
        },
        "dynamicName2": {
            "name": "test"
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering how can you deserialize this string in APEX using wrapper classes?

I tried this:

```
public class masterobj
{   public childobj Objects;    
}

public class childobj
{   public el dynamicName1;
    public el dynamicName2;     
}

public class el
{   public string name;
}

String s = '{"Objects":{"dynamicName1":{"name":"test"},"dynamicName2":{"name":"test"}}}';
masterobj mo = (masterobj)JSON.deserialize(s, masterobj.class);
```

which works well when you have declared the dynamic variable names in the class for each nested object.

The problem and the question is how can I make this work using a dynamic variable in the wrapper class. Because the object names will vary and also the number of the objects, I can't hard-code the names as they are different each time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to deserialize a structure like that with the data binding features of the json parser, you'll need to use the [streaming json parser](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_methods_system_json_overview.htm) to read it.

Comment: Why always has to be the hard way with Salesforce? :)

Comment: FWIW, there are some changes in the works to make this easier.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Map:

```
public class masterobj
{   
    Map<String, el> Objects;
}
```